# Getting Syntax Error for update query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Error:

```
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'where `membership_num`='1'' at line 1
```

Query:

```
   UPDATE `MEMBERSHIP` 
    SET `member_id`= 2, 
        `sales_id`=1,
        `duration`='3 شهور',
        `start_date`='2016-10-16',
        `end_date`='2016-10-16',
        `membership_cost_before`=500,
        `discount`=0,
        `member_ship_cost` =500,
        `membership_type` ='Silver',
        `amout_done` =500,
        `amount_reminder` = 0,
        `trainer_id` = 
     WHERE `membership_num`=1
```

Comment: Put any value for  `trainer_id` = ? before where condition

Comment: Thank You for answer it working (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trainer_id = where membership_num=1
```

You have to specify what trainer_id is. Right now you just have an = sign with nothing after so that is the syntax error.

Comment: trainer_id=NULL WHERE membership_num=1

Comment: @AhmedAlaaEldeen No problem! Glad I could help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to put value for `trainer_id=` so Put any value for trainer_id before where condition, Here I'm putting Null value  `trainer_id=Null`

Try this Query

```
UPDATE `MEMBERSHIP` 
    SET `member_id`= 2, 
        `sales_id`=1,
        `duration`='3 شهور',
        `start_date`='2016-10-16',
        `end_date`='2016-10-16',
        `membership_cost_before`=500,
        `discount`=0,
        `member_ship_cost` =500,
        `membership_type` ='Silver',
        `amout_done` =500,
        `amount_reminder` = 0,
        `trainer_id` =NULL 
     WHERE `membership_num`=1
```

**Note:** Make sure `trainer_id` column should be set not null false in database structure if you want to update null value for that.